# No inserta todos los valores seleccionado por checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```html
<?php
 
 require 'connect_db.php';
 
 $turno = $_POST['idctg_turno'];
 $entrada = $_POST['hr_entrada'];
 $salida = $_POST['hr_salida'];
 $dia = isset($_POST['idctg_dia']) ? $_POST['idctg_dia'] : null;
 
 $arraydia = null;
 
 $num_array = count($dia);
 $contador = 0;
 
 if($num_array>0){
  foreach ($dia as $key => $value) {
   if ($contador != $num_array-1)
   {
    $arraydia .= $value.' ';
    $contador++;
    } else {
    $arraydia .= $value;
   }
  }
 }
 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO ctg_horario (idctg_turno, hr_entrada, hr_salida, idctg_dia) VALUES ('$turno', '$entrada', '$salida', '$arraydia')";
 $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    echo $mysqli->error;
 
?>

<html lang="es">
 <head>
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
     <?php if($resultado) { ?>
      <h3>REGISTRO GUARDADO</h3>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <h3>ERROR AL GUARDAR</h3>
     <?php } ?>
     
     <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-primary">Regresar</a>
     
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Buenas noches realizo un formulario en el cual utilizo checkbox, solo me inserta un valor en mi campo idcgt_dia en mi BD  y necesito que se guarden todos los valores que se seleccionan en los checkbox  en mi campo de mi base de datos

```html
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <h3 style="text-align:center">NUEVO REGISTRO</h3>
   </div>
   
   <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="guardar.php" autocomplete="off">
   
   
   
   
   
    
    
    
<div class="form-group">
<label for="idctg_turno" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Turno</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT idctg_turno, descripcion FROM ctg_turno";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[idctg_turno]\">$row[descripcion] </option>";   
   
}
?>


<div class="col-sm-10">
      
     
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="idctg_turno" name="idctg_turno" placeholder="Turno" required     >
<option value="-">Selecciona el Turno</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select><br /><br /></div></div>

    

    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="hr_entrada" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Entrada</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hr_entrada" name="hr_entrada" placeholder="hr_entrada" required>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="hr_salida" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Salida</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hr_salida" name="hr_salida" placeholder="hr_salida">
     </div>
    </div>
     
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="idctg_dia" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Día</label>
     
     <div class="col-sm-10">
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
       <input type="checkbox" id="idctg_dia[]" name="idctg_dia[]" value="1"> Lunes
      </label>
      
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
       <input type="checkbox" id="idctg_dia[]" name="idctg_dia[]" value="2"> Martes
      </label>
      
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
       <input type="checkbox" id="idctg_dia[]" name="idctg_dia[]" value="3"> Miercoles
      </label>
      
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
       <input type="checkbox" id="idctg_dia[]" name="idctg_dia[]" value="4"> Jueves
      </label>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Regresar</a>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sería bueno que añadieras como estás guardando actualmente los registros a tu base de datos. es decir al INSERT INTO  que tenías en la pregunta eliminada antes

Comment: @Dev.Joel añadi como guardo mis registros en mi BD

Comment: Tal y como esta su código da la imrpesión que concatena los valores del array recibidos en `idctg_dia` como si fuera a insertar una cadena con todos estos? es así ? o desea ingresar un registro por cada item del array , ya que anteriormente  expuso que el campo de su tabla es int.

Comment: @Dev.Joel deseo ingresar un registro por cada item ya que cada día contara con hora de entrada y de salida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar lo más importante es la seguridad en su código, tal cuál está es muy vulnerable por ejemplo [a ataques de Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php) lo cuál debería erradicar aplicando o utilizando [sentencias preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) de forma correcta.

Como en su `HTML` se está enviando un "array" de valores seleccionados en los `checkboxs` deberá recibirlos como tal e iterarlos para ir ingresando los valores de forma correcta.

**Ejm** para la inserción

```
$turno = $_POST['idctg_turno'];
$entrada = $_POST['hr_entrada'];
$salida =$_POST['hr_salida'];
$arraydia = $_POST['idctg_dia'];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_clave", "midatabase");
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ctg_horario (idctg_turno, hr_entrada, hr_salida, idctg_dia) VALUES (?,?,?,?)")) {
    // Iteramos el array y como ya preparamos la sentencia 
    //solo bindeamos los parámetros
    for ($i=0; $i < count($arraydia) ; $i++) { 
        //bindeamos los parámetros para la query
        // Obteniendo el elemento del array idctg_dia
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $turno,$entrada,$salida,$arraydia[$i]);
        $stmt->execute();
    }   
}
```

Comment: ya me inserta dos item al mismo tiempo, solo una consulta en mi codigo html como le puedo hacer para que ingrese la hora de entrada y salida por cada dia, es decir seleciono el dia y le proporciono hora de entrada y salida. De igual forma se dejan vacios para iterarlos para que respete la insercion en una nueva linea en mi BD?

Comment: @Oscar_DR podría hacerlo con JavaScript agregando en una tabla lo que vaya completando. Y se aplicaría la misma lógica que en este caso para el array de idctg_dia. Pero ya sería tema para otra pregunta.

Comment: le soy honesto aun ando aprendiendo de php y no se nada de java por tal motivo realizo este pequeño proyecto en este lenguaje

Comment: @Oscar_DR JavaScript . no Java :) , igual puede formular una pregunta formal con una buena calidad y muy clara sobre esto , seguro obtendrá respuestas. Saludos y a leer :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por todas sus aportaciones y continuare aprendiendo.